# Style WPF Tabs Like Visual Studio Tabs

Tags: wpf, tabs

In WPF is it possible to style the WPF TabControl to lool like those in Visual Studio?

Instead of this: (Normal Tabs)

[image]

I will prefer this: (Styled Tabs)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible, through the use of a ControlTemplate. See [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx) for an example of a TabControl ControlTemplate. You can use this as a starting point. Good  luck!